# Distribute Blender rendering to two computers

Tags: windows, mac, memory, cpu, blender

I have two computers

- Macbook Pro Intel i7 2.9GHz with 8GB of ram
- PC with Intel i5 2.5GHz and 8GB of ram

Is it possible to distribute Blender rendering to use both of these computers? Currently Blender estimates it would take 2 days to render 1 second animation using only my Macbook.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can indicate a starting and ending frame.  I suggest you use that fact to render your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is way in Blender to sync to PCs. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender

or as Rahmound said: set an start- and endframe for Blender to render, so you can split the work to do on two PCs. Although I would recomend to render in single images (.png for example). So if one is faster, you can just give him another part to render. Afterwards the single images are easily put together in Blender or any Videoeditor. And if one picture has a mistake you can easily render it again.

Comment: So it's similar to free render farms that you need to share your PC and render the frames seperately on different PCs?